# How to resolve the warning message :" No configuration found."

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, lucene

I want to make a test to get the value of Analyzer and Directory but the console shows the following warning message:

```
WARN - No configuration found. Configuring ehcache from ehcache-failsafe.xml  found in the classpath: jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%206.0/webapps/shop1/WebRoot/WEB-INF/lib/ehcache-1.2.3.jar!/ehcache-failsafe.xml
Analyzer:null
configurationnull
```

My Spring configuration:

```
<bean id="configuration" class="cn.cultivator.shop1.lucene.Configuration" init-method="init">
        <property name="dirPath" value="C:/apache-tomcat-6.0.43/webapps/shop1/indexDir"></property>
</bean>
```

The Configuration class:

```
public class Configuration {

private Analyzer analyzer= null ;

private Directory directory =null;

public Analyzer getAnalyzer() {
    return analyzer;
}

public Directory getDirectory() {
    return directory;
}

private String dirPath = null;

public void setDirPath(String dirPath) {
    this.dirPath = dirPath;
}

public void init(){
    try {
        analyzer = new IKAnalyzer(true);
        directory = FSDirectory.open(new File(dirPath));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
}
```

The test code is:

```
    @Test
public void testConfiguratin() {
    System.out.println("Analyzer:"+configuration.getAnalyzer());
    System.out.println("configuration"+configuration.getDirectory());
}
```

Why is the value null and how do I resolve the warning message?

Answer (score 1):

That message tells you, that there is no configuration file for the [Ehcache](http://ehcache.org/) framework in your project. Therefore it loads the default configuration form its jar file. You can either remove the jar from your project, or create a ehcache.xml in your classpath ("src", "src/main/java/") and add something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache>

   <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>

   <defaultCache
        maxElementsInMemory="50000"
        eternal="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="60"
        timeToLiveSeconds="60"
        overflowToDisk="false"
        diskPersistent="false"
        diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
   />
</ehcache>
```

Since you are already using Spring, its very easy to make use of that caching in your app, [see here](http://ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/recipes/spring-annotations).